# haml: link_to nested tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a prombem when my `haml` parse this code:

```
-if link.user == current_user 
  %div{:class => "links-group d-inline"}
    = link_to "edit", edit_link_path(link) do
      = octicon("pencil", :height => 16, :class => "d-inline mt-1")
    = link_to 'destroy', link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/links/1183/edit":String

When i delete this line `= octicon("pencil", :height => 16, :class => "d-inline mt-1")` all works is good.

How fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a block to `link_to` then you need to not pass it a label to display as well.
eg

```
= link_to edit_link_path(link) do
  = octicon("pencil", :height => 16, :class => "d-inline mt-1")
```

OR

```
= link_to "edit", edit_link_path(link)
```

but not a combination of both... :)

Here is the API doc for `link_to` which gives better examples:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 1):

Also you can take a look like below -

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end

OR

link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```